# How to find the value of a zero sum game?

Tags: proof-verification, game-theory

I need to find the value of this zero sum game in a mixed strategy case.
[image]

I get all the steps until V=7/4.

Where is V=7/4 coming from?

I know how to calculate both p and q.

Comment: You say you know how to calculate the optimal strategies for each player?  Okay then, now multiply your matrix on the left and the right by the optimal strategies for each player respectively [like so](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0,3%2F4,1%2F4%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B2,0,2%7D,%7B1,2,3%7D,%7B4,1,2%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B1%2F4%7D,%7B3%2F4%7D,%7B0%7D%7D).

Comment: Im sorry i didn't quite understand... can you show me or explain more expansively?

Comment: Suppose that you have a game $A$, and you found player 1's optimal strategy is the row vector $x$ and player 2's optimal strategy is the column vector $y$.  Then the value of the game is $xAy$

Comment: Well i know that player 1 optimal strategy is (0)(3/4) and (1/4). How do i know if its a row vector or column vector? Cant really undertand it.

Comment: A row vector is written as a row.  Player 1's optimal strategy is always written as a row vector.  The probability of picking the first option, $0$ in your case, is the first entry of the row vector.  The probability of picking the second option, $\frac{3}{4}$ in your case, is written as the second entry, etc... so Player 1's optimal strategy is written as the row vector $[0,\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}]$.  Similarly Player 2's strategy is written as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{3}{4}\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.  From there, calculating $v$ is again just arithmetic, finding $xAy$

Comment: okay thanks... then to calculate V i would need to multiply player 1's optimal strategy by each row and then add up e.g  2(0)+(3/4)0+2(1/4) eccc then multiply the whole addition by the same thing but with player 2?

Comment: This is standard [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).  Calculating $xA$ first, you would find the result's first row, first column entry by multiplying each respective entry of the first row of $x$ by the respective entry of the first *column* of $A$, and then add the results.  You'll have $[0,\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{4}]\begin{bmatrix}2&0&2\\1&2&3\\4&1&2\end{bmatrix} = [0(2) + \frac{3}{4}(1)+\frac{1}{4}(4),~~~ 0(0)+\frac{3}{4}(2)+\frac{1}{4}(1),\dots]$